# Check jquery map object null or not ? for both IE and Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check javascript map object is null or empty in both chrome and IE browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to code for IE browser support in your javascript :

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

For Chrome not required due to polyfill default avaialble.

To check the map is null or not :

```
if(Object.entries(mapObj).length > 0){}
```

Comment: If you are checking the length of properties, why not use `Object.keys(mapObj).length`? No need for Polyfill